# Laravel Passport to return 403 error instead of route('login')

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm trying to get Laravel Passport to give clients a `403` response instead of a `route('login')` when they try to access a resource via REST with an invalid Authorization token.

This is my `route/api.php`

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('invoices')->group(function () {
        Route::post('', 'API\InvoiceController@create');
    });
});
```

And this is my `app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            //return route('login');
            return response()->json([],403);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the `redirectTo` gives the error `Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected`.

I'm not sure where to set my `403` response?

I'm using Laravel 5.8.

Comment: `redirectTo` expects a string or null to be returned, you're returning a `JsonResponse` object.

Comment: As previous comment mentioned, that not the place to set the response. You can customize the exeption response on  `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. But first... Are you sending the request with `"Accept: application/json"` header? By default laravel returns `{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}` with 401 status to me when I doesn't send the right token

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Yes I would like to send `"Accept: application/json"` with 401 instead.  Can you point me in the right direction on how to customize the `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to give the 401?  Because right now, the default behaviour is just the redirect that I commented out in my code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated json response, you can override the `unauthenticated` method on [/app/Exceptions/Handler.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/app/Exceptions/Handler.php).

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
// ...

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    // ...
        
    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'my custom message.'], 403);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            abort(response()->json('Unauthorized', 403));
        }
    }
}
```